# FreeBSD can't mount fdesc?

Tags: mount, freebsd, fstab

I recently had a bad UPS lead to a sudden crash of several machines.  One of them (running FreeBSD) didn't come back up until I replaced the power supply, but it's still not fully back.  Both the BIOS and the OS complain about a disk being missing; swapping around power cables and data cables and such has convinced me that the problem is the disk itself.  FreeBSD won't fully start up due to a problem mounting something from /etc/fstab:

```
Mounting local file systems: mount: /fdesc: No such file or directory
```

If I comment out the fdesc line in fstab, everything seems to come up OK.  But... that can't be good, can it? I don't know anything about fdesc besides what I've read in the past few minutes, but it seems like a low-level thing dealing with stuff like stdin and stdout, which seem important to me.

There does exist /dev/fd, which does contain /dev/fd/0, /dev/fd/1, and /dev/fd/2, and brief piping experiments at the command line seem to indicate that stdin, stdout, and stderr are all working OK.

What might be the cause of it being unable to mount /fdesc? And what horrible things will happen if I just continue to run without mounting it? How might I be able to get /fdesc back?

The contents of /etc/fstab, after I commented out the fdesc line:

```
#Device      Mountpoint  FSType  Options  Dump  Pass#
/dev/ada0p2  /           ufs     rw       1     1
/dev/ada0p3  none        swap    sw       0     0
#/dev/fd     fdesc       fdesc   rw       0     0
```

Plus a couple Samba mounts which seem to be working fine.

Comment: It's only needed for things like `bash`, which need the full `/dev/fd` behavior to do process substitution. Which release of FreeBSD is this? On 10.0, the fstype is `fdescfs` and the mount point is `/dev/fd`. I can check older releases for you.

Comment: Thanks.  It's 10.0-RELEASE.  After reading your comment, I tried bash, and piping with stdin, stdout, and stderr seem to work OK there too? And there is a /dev/fd.  Not sure what you mean by "to do process substitution"? Thanks again.

Comment: There's always a `/dev/fd/0`, `1`, and `2` - the filesystem mounted at `/dev` handles them. But if you run `join -t: <(sort /etc/passwd) <(sort /etc/group)` in bash, you'll get an error `join: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory`. But if you run `mount -t fdescfs fdescfs /dev/fd`, then that `join` command will work.

Comment: Thanks - exactly what you describe happens with the join.  But this leads me to wonder why fdesc can't be mounted from fstab, given that I can mount it from the command line.

Comment: I think the proper fstab line is `fdescfs /dev/fd fdescfs rw 0 0`. It's a mystery to me how your existing fstab line once did work.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick (except I made the first word "fdesc" instead of "fdescfs" based on some googling).

Comment: Good. I think the first word can actually be anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fdesc` line in `fstab` appears be mislocated, it should be

> fdesc /dev/fd fdescfs rw 0 0

As the first comment noted, the first colum is device name, which is ignored by `fdescfs(5)`, then the mount point, which should be `/dev/fd` to make it useful.
Also the file system type is `fdescfs`, not `fdesc`

See the man page `fdescfs(5)` for more information.